# How to use Games Howell in R, alternative to TukeyHSD

Tags: r, statistics, tukey

I do not know how to run Games Howell in R. I already did the ANOVA test and TukeyHSD test. But homogeneity is violated as I run the Levene test. So I am looking for an alternative to TukeyHSD, which is more robust.

Is there an easy way how to run an alternative to TukeyHSD which does not care about the assumption of homogeneity? I would be very grateful for the sample code. Thank you.

'crop.data' -> csv file

'species' -> there are 4 groups that I compare

'num_flowers' -> parameter

```
res.aov <- aov(num_flowers ~ species, data = crop.data)
TukeyHSD(res.aov)
```

result

```
         diff        lwr        upr     p adj
1-4    -0.2859155 -1.1548969  0.5830659 0.8297376
2-4    -3.0638889 -3.9310760 -2.1967018 0.0000000
3-4    -1.6432836 -2.5199360 -0.7666312 0.0000133
2-1    -2.7779734 -3.4454133 -2.1105335 0.0000000
3-1    -1.3573681 -2.0370607 -0.6776755 0.0000030
3-2    1.4206053  0.7432082  2.0980024  0.0000009
```

Comment: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rstatix/html/games_howell_test.html `games_howell_test(crop.data, num_flowers ~ species, conf.level = 0.95, detailed = FALSE)` maybe?